# When adding react data table component to a functional component I get an element type is invalid error

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

When I add and export react-data-table-component I get the following error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function/... You likely forgot to export your component.

My code:

```
import React from "react";

import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

// test data
const columns = [
    {
        name: 'Title',
        selector: row => row.title,
    },
    {
        name: 'Year',
        selector: row => row.year,
    },
];

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Beetlejuice',
        year: '1988',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Ghostbusters',
        year: '1984',
    },
]


export default function Attendance() {
  console.log(data);

    return (
      <DataTable
           columns={columns}
           data={data}
           selectableRows
       />
    );

}
```

I then import it into anothe rmodule like so:

```
import Attendance from "../screens/Attendance";
```

When I remove the datatable then it works fine with a regular View component.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported it in your App.js correctly? Because it is working fine here  https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-forest-mepb0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: App.css? @Mohit Maroliya B17CS036

Comment: Sorry! typo its App.js

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with 'mui-datatables' and 'react-material-ui-carousel'.

It happens when I update React and change babel config.

I fixed it by using `<Component.default>` instead of `<Component>`. Because,  when I logged this component, I saw `{__esModule: true, default: ƒ=>JSX.Element}`.

I don't know why this is happening, probably it babel config.
And so, it happens when imported components include MUI components.